# GoogleSignIn Account Information

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I'm currently able to SignIn in my app with GoogleSignIn, so in my `SignInActivity` I have the GoogleSignIn button that asks the user to choose a Google account.
In the `MainActivity` in `onStart()` method I have `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount` that return a `GoogleSignInAccount`.
From this object I can get information on account like: name, email or image.
I put all this information in the header of navigation drawer as all Google apps has, but I miss the **'background image'** that you see in the Google Plus account.
How can I get this background image? Do I have to change the GoogleSignIn method or the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot get the background image from [googleSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount) object. As you can see, there many methods but none of them can help you get the background image. Using `googleSignInAccount` can help you **`only`** retrieve a signed-in user's `basic profile information`, such as their `name`, `email address`, and `profile photo URL`.

Comment: Ok, so which method I have to use to get the background image?

Comment: There is no method that can help you get the cover image. There was a trick a few years ago when you could use this line of code `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{GOOGLE_USER_ID}?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` to get the image but isn't working anymore. Now, as you probably know, Google has ancoded the cover photo. Now it's a `.webp`, not a .jpg anymore. Even if you could get the url of the image you cannot decode the image itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But after a lot of search i find that it's possible to retrive the cover photo with Plus API... now it's deprecated but it's still working. I accept the answer for the search help...